# How to stop media player on specific event in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have 6 activities in my app. I want to play different sound throughout whole app. But the problem is that when I start second activity from first activity I want same sound continue from point where its playing in first activity. But unable to find any solution on SO. how to do this? Please help me.

I am using `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Use a service which will work across all your activities and play sound seamlessly. There's even a tutorial on how to do this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices. You can of course just use the service internally to your activities/app.

Answer (score 0):

use the application class, or any singleton pattern for that matter you can persist data across activities

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

In your activities onPause() you have to save the current progress of the track to the shared preferences, then in your activities onResume() get the progress and resume the mediaplayer...

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mediaplayer.pause();
    int progress = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
    getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("track_progress",progress).commit();
}

public void onResume() {
    int progress = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("track_progress",0);
    mediaplayer.seekTo(progress);
    mediaplayer.start();
}
```

Well yeah, or as @Brian says, use a singleton ... :)

Update as a singleton e.g.

```
public class BackgroundPlayer {

private static final String TAG = BackgroundPlayer.class.getName();

private static BackgroundPlayer instance;
public static BackgroundPlayer instance() {
    if(instance==null) instance = new BackgroundPlayer();
    return instance;
}

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void startBackgroundMusic(Context ctx, int res) {
    if(mediaPlayer==null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, res);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);           
    }
    if(mediaPlayer!=null&&!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        Log.i(TAG,"started");
        mediaPlayer.start();            
}

public void stopBackgroundMusic() {
    if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        Log.i(TAG,"stopped");
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
}

}
```

Now you can access the same instance of the BackgroundPlayer anywhere in your code with

```
BackgroundPlayer.instance()
```

and you can call

```
BackgroundPlayer.instance().startBackgroundMusic(Context, resource);
BackgroundPlayer.instance().stopBackgroundMusic();
```

anywhere. Now you have to make sure you call .startBackgroundMusic in your first activities onCreate() and call .stopBackgroundMusic in the last activity on the stack, so the sound doesn't keep going when the user leaves your app.

Comment: And is it possible to send progress to other activity if yes then how?

Comment: @EIDuderino thank you for this response. I let you know if it work properly then i accept your answer.

Comment: If it doesn't work (maybe there is a little pause between activity start and finish?) I can help you with the Singleton idea.

Comment: Yes there is a little pause please help me with singleton idea.